# DataError for a DateTime?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, traceback

I have a Django model (ReportCache) that stores reports in an SQL table. One of the fields in it is a django.db.models.DateTimeField, used for storing the last time the report was updated.

For some reason, I'm getting a DataError: value too long for type character varying(20) when trying to save a datetime to them. The datetime is generated by datetime.datetime.now(), and I have tried with and without django.utils.timezone.make_aware(), with no affect.

Full traceback is at https://gist.github.com/cyberjacob/2f1e61f83a6fbd5792b8

Any suggestions why my date is randomly too long?

Comment: Either the date field was somehow created as a varchar column in the database, or the error is about a different field altogether.

Comment: the traceback shows LastUpdate=datetime.datetime.now(), is the offending line in my code

Comment: That's clearly the first line of a multi-line statement, and is not the cause of the error; setting a variable to a date would *not* cause a database insert. Please show the context of that line: perhaps the whole runDetailedReport function, if it is not too long.

Comment: So I would guess the problem is the ReportKey field, since that is a minimum of 22 characters (depending on the length of clientId. Note also that you should *never* be calling `foo.__str__()` directly: do `str(foo)` or even better use string interpolation.

Comment: changing the length of ReportKey to 64 has fixed the issue. Can you submit that as an answer so I can accept it. Also, why should I use str() over __str__()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not seem to be with the date field, but with the ReportKey string field.

As mentioned, it is not idiomatic in Python to call the double-underscore methods like `foo.__str__()` directly. You should call the built-in functions: `str(foo)`. Even better though is to use string interpolation:

```
ReportKey = "DetailedReport.{}.{}.{}".format(year, month, clientId)
```